# Comparing most recent results from two tables using SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to compare the most recent entered value from one table with the most recent limit entered into another table. Then I want to return a single response which shows whether the limit has been exceeded. I'm somewhat new to SQL, but this is what I did to get the most recent values in each table:

```
SELECT  
(SELECT a.Current_Speed FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Current_Speed, date_entered FROM [Measured] ORDER BY date_entered DESC) AS a) AS Value1,
(SELECT b.Speed_Limit FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Speed_Limit, date_entered FROM [Limits] ORDER BY date_entered DESC) as b) AS Limit1
```

This works, as far as that goes, Although I think there must be an easier way than using five SELECTs. It returns the correct values in columns titled Value1 and Title1. I then tried to add a CASE statement to the end, as follows:

```
SELECT  
(SELECT a.Current_Speed FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Current_Speed, date_entered FROM [dbo].[Measured] ORDER BY date_entered DESC) AS a) AS Value1,
(SELECT b.Speed_Limit FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Speed_Limit, date_entered FROM [dbo].[Limits] ORDER BY date_entered DESC) as b) AS Limit1,
CASE WHEN Value1 > Limit1 THEN 'Over'
     WHEN Limit1 > Value1 THEN 'Under'
     ELSE 'Perfect!' END AS Result
```

However, this does not work, as I get an "Invalid Column Name" response for Value1 and Limit1 when executing the query.

I'm sure there must be a way to achieve what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to find it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add table definition and perhaps some sample data, an example of the output would also be helpful.

Comment: Currently there is no relationship between `Current_Speed` and `Speed_Limit`. You could be collecting current speed from yesterday and speed limit from 6 days ago. Unless this is a single road where the limits vary based on arbitrary value such as time, these two items correlating is unlikely.

Comment: @Random_User I've simplified the application, and it doesn't relate to road speed, but you're correct. Measurements are continuously being entered, and the limit can be changed at any time. The output only needs to indicate whether the most recently measured value is within the current limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the subqueries in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN m.Current_Speed > l.Speed_Limit THEN 'Over'
             WHEN l.Speed_Limit > m.Current_Speed THEN 'Under'
             ELSE 'Perfect!'
        END) AS Result
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 m.* FROM [dbo].[Measured] m ORDER BY date_entered DESC
     ) m CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT TOP 1 l.* FROM [dbo].[Limits] l ORDER BY date_entered DESC
     ) l;
```

Note the simplifications to the logic:

- Only one level of subqueries is needed for each value.
- The subqueries can use the convenience of `select *` to take all the columns.  SQL Server is smart enough to only use the columns that are needed.
- The table aliases are related to the tables defining the subqueries.  This makes it much easier to follow the query logic.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for what you want.

```
Select CASE WHEN Value1 > Limit1 THEN 'Over'
     WHEN Limit1 > Value1 THEN 'Under'
     ELSE 'Perfect!' END AS Result
From (
SELECT  
(SELECT a.Current_Speed FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Current_Speed, date_entered FROM [dbo].[Measured] ORDER BY date_entered DESC) AS a) AS Value1,
(SELECT b.Speed_Limit FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Speed_Limit, date_entered FROM [dbo].[Limits] ORDER BY date_entered DESC) as b) AS Limit1
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 Current_Speed 
            FROM [Measured] 
            ORDER BY date_entered DESC) AS Value1,
           (SELECT TOP 1 Speed_Limit 
            FROM [Limits] 
            ORDER BY date_entered DESC) AS Limit1
)
SELECT Value1, 
       Limit1,
       CASE WHEN Value1 > Limit1 THEN 'Over'
            WHEN Limit1 > Value1 THEN 'Under'
            ELSE 'Perfect!' END AS Result
FROM x;
```

OR

```
SELECT Value1, 
       Limit1,
       CASE WHEN Value1 > Limit1 THEN 'Over'
            WHEN Limit1 > Value1 THEN 'Under'
            ELSE 'Perfect!' END AS Result
FROM (SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 Current_Speed 
              FROM [Measured] 
              ORDER BY date_entered DESC) AS Value1,
             (SELECT TOP 1 Speed_Limit 
              FROM [Limits] 
              ORDER BY date_entered DESC) AS Limit1) x
```